# Android Java, получить координаты клика из View

Tags: java, android

Пишу приложение под андроид, подскажите, как получить координаты клика из view. Сам OnClick() срабатывает нормально.

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
@Override
public void onClick(View view){
        click_x=view.GetLeft(); // найдено в справке, java ругается на эти функции.
        click_y=view.GetTop();
    }

});
```

Comment: Кто сказал что методы начинаются с большой буквы? [ПОсмотри докаментация: ](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft()) `getLeft()`. Ява - это не какой нибудь БЕЙСИК совдеповский где можно игнорировать размер букв. :)

Comment: А для чего нужны координаты?

Comment: Я задолбался и не обратил внимания на размер. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте `onTouchEvent` вместо `onClick`

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int)event.getX();
    int y = (int)event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
    }
return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> `click_x=view.GetLeft();` // найдено в справке, java ругается на эти функции.

конечно он будет ругаться, потому что у тебя метод с большой буквы [пряма ссылка на док с методом](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#getLeft())